# Como dividir linhas por linhas de dois df diferentes e armazenar em um terceiro?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Tento dividir usando os metodos div e divide e ao atribuir em um novo df todos os valores estão como NaN

Comment: Qual código você rodou para obter NaN como resultado? Fica difícil reproduzir o erro sem saber exatamente o que foi feito. Foi algo como `df_2014['2014 [YR2014]'].div(df_2010['2010 [YR2010]'])`?

Comment: Exatamente isso.

Answer (score 1):

Se você especificar as colunas que deseja dividir (mesmo que cada dataframe só tenha uma coluna), é só usar o operador `/` ). O resultado é um Pandas.Series, que pode ser usado como coluna em um dataframe:

```
In [24]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({"2014": {"Albania": 5716.853}})                                                            

In [25]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({"2000": {"Albania": 3021.608}})                                                            

In [26]: df1["2014"] / df2["2000"]                                                                                      
Out[26]: 
Albania    1.89199
dtype: float64
```

Melhor do que ter cada coluna em um dataframe separado é juntar tudo:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"2014": {"Albania": 5716.853}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"2000": {"Albania": 3021.608}})
ratio = df1["2014"] / df2["2000"]
ratio.name = "Taxa de crescimento"
final = pd.concat((df1, df2, result), axis=1)
```

Representação do DF final:

```
In [37]: final                                                                                                          
Out[37]: 
             2014      2000  Taxa de crescimento
Albania  5716.853  3021.608              1.89199
```